# Add a legend form geom_area in a density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the following graph. I want to add a legend to explain the grey area in the density. Any suggestions?

[image]

The code here:

```
dd <- density(x, y, , na.rm = TRUE)
dd <- data.frame(x=dd$x,y=dd$y )

ggplot(dd, aes(x,y)) + 
 geom_line(color="black") + xlim(range(0, 45)) +
 geom_area(data = subset(dd, x >41), color="grey", fill = "grey")  +
 scale_x_discrete(limits=seq(from=0, to=45, by =5),
  labels=c("45", "40" , "35" , 
  "30", "25","20","15" , "10" , "5" , "Election")) + theme_minimal() +
 labs(title="Local Election", y="Density", x="Distance to the election(in 
  Months)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an aesthetic to your `geom_area()`, like this:

```
geom_area(data = subset(dd, x > 41), aes(fill = "x>41"))
```

This will achieve what you want, but the color won't be grey, to change the color, you need to use `scale_fill_manual()`:

```
ggplot() + .... + scale_fill_manual(values = c("x>41"="grey"))
```

Comment: This work. Thanks. But I also had to take out the parameter fill="grey" inside the layer geom_area, and leave only on the aes of  geom_area. Thank you so much!

Comment: If the answer helped you could you accept it so that people facing the same issue know that the solution works for this issue. Thanks.